# ng-options filter equal to ng-model from input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I'm trying to add conditional filter to my `ng-options`. The options should only be displayed when an id from the options array equals an id from a different select input.

The first `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-model="requestDepartment" ng-options="department.DepartmentID as department.DepartmentName for department in departments" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

The second `ng-options` with filtering:

```
<select ng-model="requestCategory" ng-options="category.CategorytName for category in categories | filter:{category.ParentID : requestDepartment}" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

The second `ng-options` should only show entries which match the ng-model from the first `ng-options`.

The structure for the data is as follows:

```
DepartmentID: 1
DepartmentName: "IT"

ParentID: 1
CategoryName: "Sharepoint"
```

So, if department "IT" is selected I only want to display categories that match the `parentID`, in this case "Sharepoint".

I have tried `filter:{category.ParentID : requestDepartment}` without luck.

Any suggestions?

Update:

I have added a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q53ro5sr/4/

Comment: Put a $watch on the first select and handle it in your controller. If you'll set up a fiddle with a controller also I'll show you how i've done it.

Comment: See my update please. I have added a fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
<select ng-model="requestCategory" 
        ng-options="category.CategoryName for category in categories | filter: { ParentID: requestDepartment }" 
        class="form-control">
      <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5g5y4pv/)